# Remove "\n\" from string

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there any way to remove "\r\" from string? 
Sofar i manage to remove only "\r" with `mystring.gsub(/\r/,"")`

How do I remove all 3 characters `\r\` ?

Comment: `\r\ ` is actually two characters; `\r` is an escape code that refers to character #13. If you mean "remove literal \r and literal \" then that would be 3 characters. Can you clarify which you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your string, do you have the literal characters "\" and "r", or do you have the escape sequence "\r"?

If you have the string `foo\r\fbar`, then your string is 8 characters long:

```
"foo\r\fbar".split(//).map(&:ord)
 => [102, 111, 111, 13, 12, 98, 97, 114]
```

What you want to remove are the `\r` and `\f` characters, or character codes 13 and 12. You *can't* remove just the leading slash in the `\f`, because `\f` is just one character. If this is your case, you can use:

```
"foo\r\fbar".gsub(/\r\f/, "")
=> "foobar"
```

However, if you have the literal sequence `foo\\r\\fbar`:

```
"foo\\r\\fbar".split(//).map(&:ord)
 => [102, 111, 111, 92, 114, 92, 102, 98, 97, 114]
```

Then you *can* remove the `\r` and the slash before the "f":

```
"foo\\r\\fbar".gsub(/\\r\\/, "")
=> "foofbar"
```

If you have the sequence `foo\r\\fbar`:

```
"foo\r\\fbar".split(//).map(&:ord)
=> [102, 111, 111, 13, 92, 102, 98, 97, 114]
```

Then you can likewise remove the `\r` and the slash before the "f":

```
"foo\r\\fbar".gsub(/\r\\/, "")
=> "foofbar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
mystring.gsub(/\r\\/,"")
```

Comment: didnt work
`2.0.0 :060 > str.gsub(/\r\\/,"")`
`=> "asdasd\r\fsdads"`

Comment: Hmm from the output you show it seems that the string is not what you say. What you show means the string has `\r` followed by `\a` which is some wierd escape sequence. Had \r been followed by \ you would get: `asdasd\r\\asdads`

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring.gsub(/\\r\\/,"")
```

Ivaylo was so close :P

I tested it on http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell, it's difficult for us to figure out what characters you actually need to remove, because you are contradicting yourself. In the title you say `"\n\"` and in the question you say `"\r\"`. Either way, here's what I'd do in order to find out exactly what I need to search for.

Starting with the string in question:

```
mystring = "\n\\"
```

I'd use the `bytes` method to have Ruby show me what I should use:

```
mystring = "\n\\"                    # => "\n\\"
mystring.bytes.map{ |b| '%02x' % b } # => ["0a", "5c"]
mystring.tr("\x0a\x5c", '')          # => ""
mystring.gsub(/\x0a\x5c/, '')        # => ""

mystring = "\r\\"                    # => "\r\\"
mystring.bytes.map{ |b| '%02x' % b } # => ["0d", "5c"]
mystring.tr("\x0d\x5c", '')          # => ""
mystring.gsub(/\x0d\x5c/, '')        # => ""
```

Dealing with escaped characters can be a pain in any programming language, but if I look at the exact bytes that make up the character I can't go wrong, as long as I'm dealing with ASCII. If it's another character set, I'll want to use the `chars` method, and adjust my pattern appropriately:

```
mystring = "\n\\"         
mystring.chars.to_a       # => ["\n", "\\"]
mystring.gsub(/\n\\/, '') # => ""
mystring.tr("\n\\", '')   # => ""

mystring = "\r\\"         
mystring.chars.to_a       # => ["\r", "\\"]
mystring.tr("\r\\", '')   # => ""
mystring.gsub(/\r\\/, '') # => ""
```